# AM Signal Modulation

Tags: matlab, signals, graphing, modulation

So I have two separate Functions here. In the first function I am generating a signal that I want to modulate. I have to take the output from the first function and use it in the second one.

```
function [output] = JoshGoldenHW3(amplitude,tau_in,t_in)


%Setting up Variables 
A = amplitude;      %The amplitude of the signal. = 1
Tau = tau_in;       %The period of the signal. = 0.010
Time = t_in;        %The time vector(Must be 2001). -0.010:0.0001:0.010


%Setting up the values for x of each period, as well as the slopes of the
%piecewise function
x = abs(mod(Time,Tau)); %Uses modulus function to figure out x value in period
x1 = 0.4*Tau;  %First slope change in period
x2 = 0.5*Tau;  %Second slope change in period
x3 = 0.9*Tau;  %Third slope change in period

%Calculating the slopes used in each period
slope1 = (A/(0.4*Tau));    %First slope calculation
slope2 = ((-A)/(0.1*Tau)); %Second slope calculation
slope3 = ((-A)/(0.4*Tau)); %Third slope calculation
slope4 = (A/(0.1*Tau));    %Fourth slope calculation

%This section defines the equations to be used for the period
eq1 = slope1*(x(x<x1)); 
eq2 = slope2*(x(x>=x1&x<x2)-(0.4*Tau)) + A;
eq3 = slope3*(x(x>=x2&x<x3)-(0.5*Tau));
eq4 = slope4*(x(x>=x3)-(0.9*Tau)) - A;


%Defining the function at each different range of x for each period
f(x<x1) = eq1;
f(x>=x1&x<x2) = eq2;
f(x>=x2&x<x3) = eq3;
f(x>=x3) = eq4;

%Plotting the graph of f(t) vs time.
plot(Time,f,'b-');
grid
xlabel('Time (Sec)');
ylabel('V(t)');
title('Signal');
axis([Time(1) Time(2001)  -2 2])
shg

output = f;

end
```

I was able to successfully call the output signal to my second function but now I'm having trouble modulating the signal and graphing it.

```
function DSB = DSBMOD

amplitude = 1;
tau_in = 0.010; %Defining Tau
t_in = -0.010:0.0001:0.010; % Defining Time range
CarFreq = 27000; %Carrier Frequency
Fc = cos(2*pi*CarFreq*t); %Carrier Signal
Sig = JoshGoldenHW3(amplitude,tau_in,t_in); %Calling Signal from previous Function

%Modulating Signal
DSB = Sig.*Fc;

figure('units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1])

%Plotting Modulated Signal
subplot(4,3,1);
plot(t_in,Sig,'g')
axis([t_in(1) t_in(2001) -2 2])
title('Original Signal');
xlabel('Time (Seconds)');
ylabel('V(t) (Volts)');
grid
shg

%Plottng original Signal
plot(Time,Sig,'b-');
grid
xlabel('Time (Sec)');
ylabel('V(t)');
title('Signal');
axis([Time(1) Time(2001)  -2 2])
shg
end
```

I feel like I'm really close but I just can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm relatively New to using Matlab so if you have a more simple way of completing this I would appreciate any and all advice.

Comment: The modulating signal is stored in `DSB`... so just do `plot(t_in, DSB);`?

Comment: When I try that I get these Error Messages

    Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

    Error in JoshGoldenHW3 (line 49)
    axis([Time(1) Time(2001)  -2 2])

    Error in DSBMOD (line 8)
    Sig = JoshGoldenHW3(amplitude,tau_in,t_in); %Calling Signal from     previous Function

Comment: Don't plot the original signal. Just plot the modulating one. The `Time` variable isn't defined in your `DSBMOD` function.

Comment: Okay so I removed the original signal plot but I still get an error with my Sig equation

Comment: `Time` has `201` elements, not `2001`. Use `axis([Time(1) Time(end) -2 2])`

Comment: Okay that worked. But seriously? I don't understand why that works. Can you please explain this. And when I Run it it displays the original signal and then the modulated. Do you know how I can get it to display only The modulated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code

```
axis([xmin xmax ymin ymax])
```

sets the x-axis and y-axis limits for the current axes. Line

```
axis([Time(1) Time(2001)  -2 2])
```

means that the minimum x-limit is the fist element of `Time` (or `t_in`, which appears to be the same) and the maximum x-limit is 2001th-element of `Time`. However, `Time` contains only 201 elements because it is equal to `-0.010:0.0001:0.010` (i.e. it contains elemenys from -0.01 to 0.01 with the step value 0.0001).

It s better not to use a constant for the index of the last element of `Time` because the size of your array can change in the future. Instead you can use `Time(end)` construction. When used as an index, `end` means the last array index, thus `Time(end)` is the last array element.

And, as rayryeng had already said, `plot(t_in,DSB,'g')` will plot the modulated signal

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I was able to graph the signal after making those corrections.